# Where is the api reference for nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, api, reference

I may be going mental, but I can not find any api reference material for nhibernate. I've found plenty of manuals, tutorials, ebooks etc but no api reference. I saw the chm file on the nhibernate sourceforge page, but it doesn't seem to work on any of my PCs (different OSes)

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, documentation isn't NHibernate's strong point.

Comment: Looking at the NH source, there's virtually no XML documentation for the entire project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a good book that covers a lot, and there is the html documentation on the site (which also comes as a book)

(the book would be manning - nHibernate in Action - a little outdated, but a good start)

Here is the [link](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html) to the online reference

Comment: Ok, I did see the link you posted. I'll go through that. I'm just suprised there isn't one of those big lists of every class and every method etc.

Thanks for the tip on the book, if I stick with nh (I suspect I will) then I'll give it a try :)

Comment: You should be able to run the included documentation files (nhibernate.xml) through Sandcastle and create your documentation file.

Answer (score 8):

I just found this one:

http://web.archive.org/web/20141001063046/http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/index.html

It doesn't seem to be official, but at least it *looks* like an API reference... unlike the official reference, which mostly describes concepts and mappings without any information about classes and members.

Comment: The link is broken for me.

Comment: @KennyEvitt, I'm not surprised... Also, if you're here, it means that 5 years  later, NH still doesn't have an official API documentation...

Comment: They do; at least for the latest version. http://nhibernate.info/ is in GitHub – [the repo](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate.github.io). Or rather they have the "reference" docs for the latest version. That's actually what I was looking for. I opened [an issue in their GitHub-sites repo (for the 'info' site) to add the reference docs, and possibly real API docs, for past versions](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate.github.io/issues/7).

Comment: @KennyEvitt  I updated it to archive.org , but it is waiting for my edit to be peer-reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no class references publicly available on Internet as far as I know. You may build it from the source. Clone [them](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core), build the `NHibernate.sln` solution, then go into `doc` folder, ensure you have prerequisites indicated in `reference\readme.txt` file, and run `nant doc`. This will generate the class reference in the `build` folder.

Otherwise the most commonly used API are not wide, and most of them are xml documented with intellisens working in Visual Studio. The [reference documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html) has the advantage of giving more context, probably helping avoiding pitfalls like believing `ISession.Update` is to be used for updating entities (this is wrong, you do not need it unless you use detached entities, or entities coming from another session).

Official [documentation reference](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html) is on https://nhibernate.info.

Sub-links:

- [Global documentation list](https://nhibernate.info/doc/index.html)
- [Reference](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html) (What I mostly use, especially following sub parts.)

  - [Configuration](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html)
  - [Mapping - basic / entities](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html). (Add mapping xsd definition file in any or your solution folders for letting VS know it and give you intellisens in your hbm mappings.)
  - [Mapping - collections](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html)
  - [Querying - general](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-querying). Do not miss the named queries feature in [The IQuery interface](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface).
  - Querying APIs:

    1. [HQL](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html). I mostly use HQL with named queries, in mappings, for queries not dynamically built. They get parsed and validated when building session factory, which normally occurs at application startup, so it is almost as good as compile time validation. Checks log4net logs to get detailed reasons of named query parsing failures.
    2. [Criteria API](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html). I view it as the historical way of dynamically building queries in code, to be preferred over constructing HQL strings.
    3. [QueryOver API](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html). Based on Criteia API, with lambda expression support for having compile time validation of queried entities namings. Should be preferred over Criteria API in my opinion.
    4. [Linq API](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html). Great for dynamically built queries. Bear in mind that its implementation translates your queries to HQL. With complex queries, it may generate unsupported HQL constructs. Having knowledge of HQL capabilities allows a better understanding of how to write a supported Linq query for complex cases. (By example, for a complex order by, better use an explicit linq sub-query in the `OrderBy` rather than using a collection mapped on your queried entity.)
    5. [Native SQL](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html). Well, quite self-explanatory. To be used by example when you need some SQL special feature not available through other querying APIs (SQL server full-text, select for xml, ...), and that you do not wish to extend those other APIs. You may also call stored procedures. When using native SQL, I favor SQL named queries.
  - [Modifying data](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html), from [Updating objects](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-updating) to [Flush](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-flushing), and [Exception handling](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions).
  - [Performances](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html).

    1. [Batch fetching](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch). About this, you may read [my post here](/a/36070727/1178314) for a detailed explanation of why lazy loading can be very efficient with NHibernate, thanks to batch fetching. This single feature will always cause me to prefer NHibernate over Entity Framework, till it ceases being lacking in EF.
    2. [Second level cache](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-cache). Another great NHibernate feature,  lacking native support in EF. Beware, you must use transactions for leveraging this. It allows NHibernate to automatically evict cached entries for you as you change data through your application process. Without transactions, NHibernate will disable the second level cache as soon as you start changing data, for avoiding letting the cache yield you stale data.
  - [Interceptors](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-interceptors). This is one way among many allowing to customize NHibernate inner working. NHibernate is very strong at allowing you to extend it. You may also add your own HQL extensions as [here](/a/12112988/1178314), your own linq2NH extension as [here](/a/36211132/1178314) (all are answers from me). And there are other ways, see this [list](/a/11469134/1178314) for linq2NH extensibility solutions.

Moreover, a class reference will very likely be near the [Hibernate one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/). There is so many internals APIs supporting its implementation that is not much usable.

Why are such API not hidden (internal, private, ...)? Not hiding them is required for allowing the great extensibility capabilities of NHibernate. Those capabilities are a must have in my opinion. In contrast, it is so hard to fix some other .Net project shortcomings, due to lacks of extensibility they suffer. (MVC [`FileResult` and the `TweakDispositionAsInline`](/a/34994044/1178314) I had to use instead of just being able of overriding some method, or try extend [linq-to-entities](/questions/tagged/linq-to-entities), see [this](/a/10942043/1178314).)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, get [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and point it at NHibernate.dll.  It's not quite the same as real API documentation, but it's not half bad.